# How to create a query when the entire value of the element's attribute changes dynamically

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I am trying insert an amount on the field which has the below element but I can't figure out what code I should use as the input id and name are dynamically changing every time I access to the page. Below is the newly extracted element.

```html
<div class="field-item dataValueWrite">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td nowrap="" align="left">
<div id="28603ErrorCUSTOM" class="" style="display:none;">
 <span class="" errid="" title="Please enter a valid amount" 
       id="28603PegaRULESErrorFlag"></span></div>
 <input id="28603" name="28603" 
   onchange="changedInputAmountInCurrencyDisplay(this , '2' , '.' , '.' , ',' , 'false' ); " 
   class="rightJustifyStyle" type="text" size="10" value="">
  <script> formatCurrencyBeforeLoad(document.getElementById('28603'),'2','.', 'false'); </script>
  <input id="28603HIDDEN" name="$PAcqCaseCreation$pMessageAmountUSD"
       type="hidden" value="0.00">
  <script> formatCurrencyBeforeLoad(document.getElementById('28603HIDDEN'),'2', '.' , 'false'); </script> 
&nbsp;USD  
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: please update to include your current code. The element has other attributes besides id and name btw - why is using those not an option? How does the id and name change each time?

Comment: I am not sure what code to use as doc.getElementsByName or doc.getElementById doesn't work. This is because every time I load the page the number of the id and name changed.

Comment: We cannot see what you are looking at.  Please show us the html.  The "Below" element was not included in your description.

Comment: Just include your current code and explain what isn't working. If you already had solved this you wouldn't be posting here would be my guess :-)

Comment: My guess is that the website is doing it on purpose to prevent people from doing what you are trying to do. What website is it?

Comment: What is its parent element? That unique?

Comment: I have added the element for the particular field on top. By the way I tried this code: doc.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.querySelector("div[class='field-item dataValueWrite']").Value = fileLink11 but not working

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something along the line of the following -- I don't know if any of this will work..

```
// get all div element in DOM
Set divs = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("div")
// loop through all div elements
For Each div In divs
    // do things here
        For Each elem In div.getElementsByTagName("onchange")
            If InStr(elem.Value, "changedInputAmountInCurrencyDisplay") > 0 Then YAHOO: Exit For
        Next elem
Next div
```

The relevant part is using InStr to find part of the text.  It could also look for HIDDEN, and then everything to the Left of that is the secret sauce that changes each time, but which you now know and can then getElementByID.

```
InStr(elem.ID, "HIDDEN") > 0
```

Comment: I tried the suggested code but was unsuccessful. It gave me an error message: "Sub or Function not defined" on the word Yahoo. Nothing happen if I replace it with IE.document.getElementsByTagName("div") = sheet1.Range("B2")

Comment: "YAHOO" was meant as a place holder for you to substitute your code for what to do when the element was successfully found.  If the error message occurred during running of the code, then it probably found the "changed..." element, and thus the  id="28603". So at that moment you might want to replace YAHOO with say  elem.value = sheet1.Range("B2")

Comment: I have made the changes according to your advised but the result is still the same. The field still not being updated with the amount that is on my worksheet.

Comment: Anyone can help?